# R : solve.QP always shows constraints are inconsistent

Tags: r

It always say   Error in solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq = 2) : 
  constraints are inconsistent, no solution!
I checked the matrix and data and cannot find the reason.

```
betatargetstartegy<-function(beta,targetbeta,Re,C,lamda,Wp)
{
  dvec=Re
  Dmat=2*lamda*C
  Amat=cbind(beta,1,diag(13),-diag(13))
  bvec=c(targetbeta,1,rep(-2,26))-t(Amat)%*%Wp
  result=solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec,meq=2)$solutions+Wp
  return(result)
}

t=c(0.5,1,1.5)
Wp=t(t(rep(1/13,13)))
a=expected_return(60,65)
b=covariance(60,65)
betatargetstartegy(beta,t,a,b,0.5,Wp)
```

Here are the data in the pictures[image]

[image]